# undefined reference to _imp

Tags: c++, 64-bit, mingw, dllimport

I am compiling a c++ with occasional C linkage in mingw.

The linker shows it cannot find
w.cpp (253): undefined reference to `_imp__lua_tolstring'
According to my readings... it should be __imp__lua_tolstring
as the linkage as C

```
extern "C"
{
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>
#include "lualib.h"
}
```

In another answer, I read
"You then fixed it with extern "C", now you got the single added underscore for cdecl, turning *imp* into __imp_"
But that does not happen to me... WHat could be the reason?

I used a command to list the content of the library
nm.exe -gC  liblua51.a

```
00003.o:
0000000000 I __imp_luaL_addstring
           U _head_liblua51_a
0000000000 T luaL_addstring

00002.o:
0000000000 I __imp_luaL_addlstring
           U _head_liblua51_a
0000000000 T luaL_addlstring

00001.o:
0000000000 I __imp_luaJIT_version_2_0_4
           U _head_liblua51_a
0000000000 T luaJIT_version_2_0_4
```

as you can see there are two underscores there.

Comment: Are you actually linking library exporting stuff declared in those headers?

Comment: not sure if the problem is that or somehow the names do not meet.